# Understanding Bauer's Introduction to Measure Theory

Tags: measure-theory, circles, geometric-construction

On the first page of chapter $1$ in Bauer's book *Measure and Integration Theory* one can read:

The limits of such elementary considerations are already reached in defining the area of an open disk $K$, to which end one proceeds thus: a sequence of open $3\cdot2^{n-1}$-gons $E_n$ ($n\in\mathbb{N}$) is inscribed in $K$, with $E_1$ being an open equilateral triangle, and the vertices of $E_{n+1}$ being those of of $E_n$ together with the intersections of the circle with the radii perpendicular to the sides of $E_n$. Thus $E_{n+1}$ consists of $E_{n}$ together with its $3\cdot2^{n-1}$ edges and the open isoceles triangles which have these edges as hypothenuses and vertices on the circle. Since $K$ is the union of of all the $E_n$, it looks like a "mosaic of triangles", that is, like a union of disjoint open triangles and segments (namely, common sides of various triangles). The following broader formulation of (B) therefore leads to a definition of the area of the disk $K$:

(C) If $(A_n)$ is a sequene of pairwise disjoint sets, and $A_n$ has numerical measure $\alpha_n$ ($n\in\mathbb{N}$), then $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n$ has numerical measure $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\alpha_n$.

So far so good but then Bauer writes:

If we replace $K$ and every $E_n$ by its topological closure, this method would not lead to a plausible definition of the area of a closed disk $\bar{K}$, because $\bar{K}$ is not the union of the closures $\bar{E}_n$ of the above constructed polygons $E_n$.

Why is this so? In my mind I have the following picture:

[image]

Comment: The closure of $K$ contains the complete circumference of $K$. The union of the closures $E_n$ does not contain the whole circumference. It contains only those points of the circumference of $K$, which are vertices of $E_n$ lying on this circumference.

Comment: @trancelocation Is this because the set of points on the circle is uncountable but there are only countably many points of the circle corresponding to vertices of the polygons?

Comment: Exactly. So it is.

Comment: @trancelocation Thanks a lot! But in any case the area of the circumference should be zero so I could used closed polygons to approximate its area no?

Comment: Of course, but to do so you need a sound concept of sets of measure $0$. Since you are still in the first chapter of your book this concept hasn't probably worked out yet.